# What are the best swords?

Tags: the-witcher-3

What are the best steel and silver swords in the game? I have a 300 damage silver sword and 260 damage steel one. If you know of any better swords, what level do you have to be and where are they found?

Comment: This is really going to depend on what stats you value, unless you mean "What are the highest-damage swords in the game?". I am also unsure how much RNG goes into drops.

Comment: the best that I have come across so far are the fully upgraded Witcher school weapons, I am at level 36 and there are not a great deal of high levels quests that I have not completed, however as @Jeeva mentions there may be some better RNG gear available.

Comment: Yeah, the various bits of upgradable Witcher gear are generally held to be the best by a fair amount of damage. But, rng...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno...for the most part, the various witcher school gear is amongst the best you can craft. They are typically over-spec'd as it is, probably usable well into your 40's. However, if you venture about and do monster contracts and explore ruins/ tunnels etc. you'll find higher level gear than even that of your master crafted witcher school gear. 
I can't remember the name, but I found one such sword in a vampire's crypt, I think. Far south of Midscope, in an abandoned village overrun by ghouls. Do the monster contract and there and you should get this sword as a drop and/ or in the nearby chest. It's one of those relic sword designs that has an "S" shape running the whole length of the blade, like waves...looks cool. Kind of like a Celtic design. It's a level 37 steel relic sword and does more base damage than my master craft witcher cat school steel sword, although, my Cat School has the best attributes. What I wonder, though, is if your level determines your loot. I have run through this game 3 times(story) and the last two times I was getting a pretty sweet looking level 27 relic sword that had knuckle guards and a serrated blade, from near the lighthouse that is south of Novigrad, on an island and in a serpent's nest. This last time through, I was very low level and didn't get that same sword and instead, got some other level 17 relic sword. So you might not get the sword I got from that crypt, until you are around 30.